# Hibernate & Java - mapping similar cols

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

How would I map elegantly a table that has let's say 15 similar columns like:

```
NOTE1_TXT    VARCHAR2(80)  
NOTE2_TXT    VARCHAR2(80)   
NOTE3_TXT    VARCHAR2(80)
```

etc

```
NOTE15_TXT   VARCHAR2(80)
```

The db structure cant be changed.

I really hate having to add 15 fields with getter/setter methods:

```
@Column(name = "NOTE1_TXT")
private String claimNoteText1;
```

Tks,

Comment: In addition to @brainOverflow's answer, you can also omit getter/setters. Hibernate can work without them. But that's not recommended OOP-wise.

Answer (score 2):

If your entity class members can have the same name as the database fields, then there is no need for  the "@Column" annotations.
And the IDEs can generate the getters/setters for you (for ex: Eclipse has a "Source" menu with a "Generate Getters and Setters" option).

Comment: I know about the omission of the "@Column" annotations and the generation of the getters/setters but it's still not a pretty solution. I would have liked to see something simpler, like one index-based field (without using reflection as well). It seems stupid having to repeat all those 15 similar fields...